# Python tornado server loses the connections

Tags: python, http, tornado

I have a python http server with tornado framework. After several requests, it becomes unavailable.  In the browser page is not available too. After about 20 seconds of inactivity, it starts to work again.

100,000 queries contain about 10 exceptions. At this load the server process consumes about 30% CPU.

Why server becomes unavailable?

Server:

```
start_port = 4400
workers = 1

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(1000))
        self.write(data)


def server_process(port):
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)

    http_server.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in xrange(workers):
        port = start_port + i
        print 'process started on %d port' % port
        p = Process(target=server_process, args=(port,))
        p.start()
```

Client:

```
def f():
    for i in xrange(500000):
        try:
            r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:4400')
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print i, str(r.text)
        except:
            print traceback.format_exc()
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for j in xrange(1):
        p = Process(target=f)
        p.start()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/test/client.py", line 16, in f
    if i % 100 == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4400): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)
```

Updated:

Experimentally picked a value of 300 requests per second the hardware server (not process). This value does not depend on the number of processes running tornado. Adding nginx as proxy server does not helped.

Server was running on ubuntu server 12.04 and linux mint 16. It looks like this limitation depends on debian operation system.

Comment: tornado is single threaded, maybe the requests getting backed up as the server is unable to handle them all: http://papercruncher.com/2013/01/15/truly-async-with-tornado/

Comment: Your client sends requests only to one single process what runs on port 4400. Perhaps this is the reason you see no difference when changing the number of server processes.

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you return only one character instead of 1000 for each request would the number of requests per seconds increase to several tens of thousands?

Comment: The reason you see a 300 req/sec per process is because tornado is able to process only one request at a time. To build the random string you return it takes approx 0.003 secs on my PC. 1/0.003 ~ 333 requests per second.

Comment: Port is hardcoded at this example. Other test require more workers in server script and random port at client script. A have got 400req/sec with data at one character, but after about 36000 requests server became unavailable again. The problem is unavailability of server, not req/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Multiprocessing.Process is a bad idea for several tornado processes. I am using tornado.process instead.